# z-index for <map> image

Tags: html, z-index

On my website I've mapped an image as you can see below:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:1298px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="img2" src="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/pictures/sfondogs.png" usemap="#img2" border="0" width="1298" height="660" alt="" />
<map id="_img2" name="img2">
<area shape="rect" coords="35,26,110,99" href="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/application.html" alt="" title="If we are recruiting, you can ask for join our staff."    />
<area shape="rect" coords="1181,27,1256,100" href="http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/sendrecord.html" alt="" title="Send us your VRs."    />
</map>
</div>
```

I would like put a text area in front of the mapped image, so I though I could use the `z-index` property.

```
img
{
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```

In the body there is a textarea (id="txtarea"). By the way the mapped image doesn't appear center aligned on the screen; could you help me? I'm using `<body background="/persbg.jpg">` as page background.

Comment: change the position to relative

Comment: @Anna.P You should put that as an answer with (some?) content about why it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img
{
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

since position:absolute will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself. Hence its not positioning in center as you expected.